# Flutter check list is contain by item

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 lists one from phone (contacts list) and the other one from server.

- **What I'm trying to do is:** that check server data are contain with numbers of the phone and show related buttons to user.
- **The issue is:** that it always show else part (its always falling to false)

`Code`

*Each part is commented for better understanding*

```
List<Contact> contacts = []; // <-- list of contacts in phone
List serverContacts = []; // <-- the data that coming from server which is include phone numbers to be check against phone contacts



// This part is inside my ListTile as `trailing`
trailing: serverContacts.contains(contact.phones != null ? contact.phones!.elementAt(0).value:'') ?
TextButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.chat, color: Colors.grey[600],),
    onPressed: () {
    //
    },
) :
TextButton( // <-- it always show this part
    child: Icon(Icons.sms, color: Colors.grey[400],),
    onPressed: () {
    //
    },
),
```

And here is data that comes from server

```
{
    "id":4,
    "name":"John",
    "username":"john",
    "phone":"+41000000000", // <-- to be check against phone contacts
    "photo":null
}
```

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: and how you're assigning value to the ``contact`` variable? Also, you're trying to access the property named ``phones`` ( ``contact.phones`` ) which ig should be ``phone`` if I am not wrong and in the JSON there is ``phone`` not ``phones``

Comment: @OMiShah Yes `contacts` list is assigned to phone contacts list, and I am using [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service) which return as `phones` not `phone` (it's out of my hand) so basically what I'm trying to do is to match server `phone` value to phone contacts `phone value at element 0 (which is first phone number in case contact has several)`

Comment: try printing ``contact.phones`` and see what does it returns. May be the list is empty

Comment: @OMiShah it returns `Instance of 'Item'` also it is possible to be empty that's why I have null check in my code `contact.phones != null ? contact.phones!.elementAt(0).value:''`

Answer (score 0):

`Solved`

Here is how I done it:

```
String? contactPhone = contact.phones != null ? flattenPhoneNumber(contact.phones!.first.value.toString()):'';
final foundPeople = serverContacts.where((element) => element['phone'] == contactPhone);
```

Then

```
trailing: foundPeople.isNotEmpty ? ... : ...,
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to compare phone number it is better to map your list first because .contain method does not work with custom classes unless you define == operator for that class, so i suggest that you map your lists to List first

```
List<String> contactPhones = contacts.map((c)=>c.phone??"").toList()
List<String> serverPhones = serverContacts.map((c)=>c.phone??"").toList()
```

now based on what you what check above list for your conditions